# knitr::spin does not set global chunk options from the command line

Tags: r, command-line, knitr, r-markdown

When I generate my .md and .html files with the following code using knitr::spin instead of knitr:knit on the command line, it completely ignores the global chunk options:

```
Rscript -e "require(knitr)" -e "knitr::spin('script.R')" \
        -e knitr::opts_chunk[['set']](include=FALSE)"
```

Could you tell me please how to set global options from the command line with spin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the global chunk options *before* you `spin()` the R script, e.g.

```
Rscript -e "library(knitr)" -e "knitr::opts_chunk[['set']](include=FALSE)" \
  -e "knitr::spin('script.R')"
```